# Count cells containing only time

Tags: time, count, cell, countif

I have a column which contains time, numbers, text, and blank cells.
Question is: How do I just count the cells containing only time values. I don't need the total (sum) of time, just need to know how many cells contain a time value. Using Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `=COUNTIF(F12:F22,"<=1.00")` put you range instead of `F12:F22`

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear! please accept the answer if it worked